# Understanding how CakePHP 3 is serving static images

Tags: apache, cakephp

I have an image located in the `webroot/uploads/files` folder. This image is being served statically by CakePHP. I am trying to better understand how to control this mechanism. I have removed every occurrence of `$routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);` from my app and plugins. My app therefor currently does not function. However, the static images are still being served.

Where should I be looking next to prevent the serving of static images? Once I have disabled it, I am going to try and create a controller to take care of it with more fine-grain control.

Comment: You're using URLs like `/uploads/files/whatever.png`? CakePHP will, by default, not be doing anything with those, because the `.htaccess` file will be telling Apache to serve those directly.

Comment: You need custom middleware https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html at first place in your Application::middleware(). Inside custom middleware put your code logic

Comment: @GregSchmidt You are correct! It was apache serving it and not CakePHP. I have posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP is not serving these images. Instead they are being served by the Apache web server. The serving of these images can be deactivated by making use of of entries in the appropriate .htaccess file.

In my case I added the following code to the .htaccess file in the webroot folder inside of my CakePHP app, which is located in the default Apache /var/www/html/ directory structure.

I deactivated image serving with the follow code:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/app/webroot/uploads/files>
    Options -Indexes
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Alternately, you could store files that have access controls around them somewhere outside the `webroot` folder.